# Let $f_n:[1,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}\chi_{[n,\infty)}(x)$. Does $\int f_n \to \int f$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f_n:[1,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}\chi_{[n,\infty)}(x)$.  Does $\int f_n \to \int f$?

I know it is an application of DCT but I really don't know to come up with a bound that would satisfy the hypothesis of DCT. Something like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ should work but $\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: As defined, we have $\int f_n = +\infty$ but $f = 0$ so $\int f = 0$.

Comment: $\int f_n = \infty$ for all $n$. On the other side $f=0$ so $\int f = 0$.

Comment: what is an integrable 'g' which will bound $f_n$ so that I can apply DCT @mechanodroid

Comment: We have $\int f_n \not\to \int f$ so you cannot apply DCT, the integrable function $g$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Furthermore, the sequence is monotone decreasing.  It is also an example showing why you need monotone increasing for the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comments, the first thing to see is that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise everywhere as $n\to\infty$. Also $\int_{[n,\infty)}f_n=+\infty$ no matter what is $n\in[1,\infty)$ so if you suppose that the DCT holds true, then by intechanging limit and integrals you would obtain $\lim\int_{[n,\infty)}f_n=+\infty=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim f_n=0$ which is not possibly true.